# explore elements of a categorical vector in rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

my question is trivial, but I'm new with RCPP and still have not mastered. I wanted to make a function that given a categorical vector and two integers returns the subset of vector content between the two integers. You know, ["A","B","C","D] and 1 and 2, returns me ["B","C"].
I did the next code but doesn't work.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::StringVector Segment(Rcpp::StringVector x, int start, int end) {
  Rcpp::StringVector s(end-start+1);
  for(int i=start; i <= end; i++){
    s[i]=x[i];
    }
  return(s);
}
```

Comment: Rcpp does not have a dedicated type for Factor or Ordered.  You can only work on the levels vector.  Which would suggest an IntegerVector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `CharacterVector`. The solution could be like this.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
CharacterVector Segment( CharacterVector x, int start, int end){
  CharacterVector r(end-start+1);
  int ind=0;
  for( int i=0; i<=r.size(); i++){
    if((i>=start) & (i<=end)){
      r[ind]=x[i];
      ind+=1;
    }
  }
  return(r);
}
```